# How can I force Pandas dataframe column query to return only str and not interpret what it is seeing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have an excel spreadsheet that has four column names: "Column One, Column Two, Jun-17, and Column Three"

When I display my column names after reading in the data I get something very different from the "Jun-17" text I was hoping to receive.  What should I be doing differently?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Sample.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

print("Column headings:")
print(df.columns.tolist())

Column headings:
['Column One', 'Column Two', datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 17, 0, 0), 'Column Three']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your column names is a `datetime` object. You can rename it to a string using `datetime.strftime`. Example below.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Column One', 'Column Two',
                           datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 17, 0, 0), 'Column Three'])

df.columns.values[2] = df.columns[2].strftime('%b-%d')

# alternatively:
# df = df.rename(columns={df.columns[2]: df.columns[2].strftime('%b-%d')})

df.columns
# Index(['Column One', 'Column Two', 'Jun-17', 'Column Three'], dtype='object')
```

If you see this problem repeatedly, wrap your dataframe in a function:

```
def normalise_columns(df):
    df.columns = [i.strftime('%b-%d') if isinstance(i, datetime.datetime) \
                  else i for i in df.columns]
    return df

normalise_columns(df).columns
```

Comment: The issue I have is that I'm receiving hundreds of spreadsheets and I'm trying to match the content of the  headers up with a set of parsers that I have for processing the data in the sheets.   This is the first one that I have run across that had something that could be interpreted as a date or a numeric.  Is there anyway to tell it not to try to be so smart?

Comment: That's the ticket.  I can go back to work this morning looking smarter.  It also gives me the flexibility of detecting other object types and adding them to my list of special cases to check for.

Comment: Using rename was the proper thing to do.  Setting the columns.values only set the column name but didn't allow me to iterate through the rows and query by column name since the new name didn't propagate throughout the df with the extra sauce included in the rename.